# Java: Issue running from command line

Tags: java, compilation

I'm writing a program in Eclipse, and running it from the command line. In an earlier version of the program, it took no arguements, and I could run it fine as `> java foo`. I've since added a couple of arguments, and need to run it as `> java foo file1.txt file2.txt`. When I run this, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` error. Even when I include the classpath, i.e. `> java foo file1.txt file2.txt -cp .` it still doesn't work.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
Here is the complete stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cuny/pausePred/TemplateToCharTestVector (wrong name: edu/cuny/pausepred/TemplateToCharTestVector)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Comment: Include the stack-trace for the exception; it will give the name of the class it was looking for.  Most likely you need to give the fully-qualified name.  And the classpath needs to be before the class name or else it's treated as a parameter to the program.

Comment: @DelShekasteh - Yes, I did

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey - I just added the stack trace. Could you point me to where I should look?

Comment: It cannot load `edu.cuny.pausePred.TemplateToCharTestVector`, which is a class which foo uses.

Answer (score 1):

- Write the full directory path then compile all classes
- Write the full directory and run the class that contains the main() method

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, I'm now getting the error `Could not find or load main class [full directory path]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run the class that contains the main() method. When compiling a file named 'BankAccounts'...


compile like this: <file directory> BankAccounts.java then


run like this: <file directory> BankAccounts

Comment: Take notice of my revised answer.

Comment: Post what you're typing exactly & the error you're currently getting in command line.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake for beginners in using Java is misunderstanding class names and the classpath.

A class name is a fully qualified thing which includes the package; the compiler lets you refer to a class using its base name, which is a convenience to keep programming sane.  The actual name of your class is `<package>.foo`.

The classpath must include the root of any packages which you are using.  So if your package for foo is `edu.cuny.pausePred` then the class name for foo is `edu.cuny.pausePred.foo` and the classpath must include the directory which contains `edu`, not the directory which contains `foo`.

You command line should be something like:

```
jave -cp the-directory-root-for-java-sources foo file1.txt file2.txt
```

noting that this assumes that the two data files are in the current directory.

As an aside, note that a class base name should be lead uppercase, so `Foo`, not `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  edu/cuny/pausePred/TemplateToCharTestVector 
  (wrong name: edu/cuny/pausepred/TemplateToCharTestVector)
```

Paths in java are case-sensitive.  `pausepred` is not the same as `pausePred`